# Using PythonAnywhere as a game server

Tags: python, sockets, flask, twisted, pythonanywhere

I'm building a turn-based game and I'm hoping to implement client-server style networking. I really just need to send the position of a couple of objects and some other easily encodable data. I'm pretty new to networking, although I've coded some basic stuff in socket and twisted. Now, though, I need to be able to send the data to a computer that isn't on my local network, and I can't do port forwarding since I don't have admin access to the router and I'm also not totally sure that would do the trick anyways since I've never done it. So, I was thinking of running some Flask or Bottle or Django, etc. code off PythonAnywhere. The clients would then send data to the server code on PythonAnywhere, and when the turn passed, the other client would just go look up the information it needed on the server. I guess then the server would act as just a data bank with some simple getter and setter methods. My question is how can this be implemented? Can my Socket code on my client program talk to my Flask code on PythonAnywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, client code can talk to your project at PythonAnywhere, as you will be given a unique project url like http://yourblogname.pythonanywhere.com/. Your server will listen the 80 port at that url.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what sort of connection your clients need to make to the server.  PythonAnywhere supports WSGI, which means "normal" HTTP request/response interactions -- GET, POST, etc.  That works well for "traditional" web pages or web apps.

If your client side needs dynamic, two-way connections using non-HTTP protocols, using raw sockets, or even websockets, PythonAnyhwere doesn't support that at present.